# How does spring aop proxy object knows which advice to call

Tags: spring, proxy, spring-aop

I kbow Proxy object extends the target class and overrides non final methods. My question is, when the proxy object overrides target method, what extra code it adds to target method that makes advice to get called? And how proxy knows when to call an advice,before, after etc?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a bit too broad since the code used is quite complex.

I'm not sure why do you want to know the exact implementation details but as starting point you should check how Spring AOP works:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop

Spring implements proxying by using CGLIB or the JDK depending the situation (i.e.: if you implement your beans using interfaces, Spring will try to use the JDK).
You can check the Proxying mechanisms here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-proxying

From there you can search for the libraries and check the code used for proxying.

I hope this serves you as a starting point for your reasearch.